# How to read cbr in linux?

Tags: documents, cbr

I tried mcomix to read .cbr but it says archive format not supported. Calibre isn't working either, any idea on how to open .cbr files under linux ?

Comment: Does Okular/Evince work? Is the .cbr file a comic book? Some website online says calibre should be able to open that (https://linuxaria.com/recensioni/comic-book-viewers-for-linux)

Comment: Install libunrar and rar, mcomix should work and calibre is definitively not meant for reading comics.

Answer (score 1):

On linux you can open CBR with `evince`. But for a better experience portability PDF is recomanded. `calibre` can convert it to pdf. Unfortunately **`calibre`** changes the image, which is very important to CBR and CBZ, **so to have minimal loss of quality, practically using  the original `jpg` inside the CBR**(CBZ) you need to use `img2pdf`, I use this commands:

First need to install this:

```
sudo apt install img2pdf p7zip-full
```

1) This to make a `pdf` file out of every `jpg` image without loss of either resolution or quality:

```
ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
```

2) This to concatenate the `pdf`pages into one:

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
```

I made this batch files ([github here](https://github.com/eduardflorinescu/cbr2pdf))

### **./cbr2pdf.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xev
ORIGINAL_FOLDER=`pwd` 
JPEGS=`mktemp -d`
cp "$1" "$JPEGS"
cd "$JPEGS"
7z e "$1" 
ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
cp "$JPEGS/combined.pdf" "$ORIGINAL_FOLDER/$1.pdf"
```

### cat cbz2pdf.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -xev
ORIGINAL_FOLDER=`pwd` 
JPEGS=`mktemp -d`
unzip "$1" -d "$JPEGS"
cd "$JPEGS"
ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
cp "$JPEGS/combined.pdf" "$ORIGINAL_FOLDER/$1.pdf"
```